# Assigning class member via function output doesn't work after querying?

Tags: c++

The title might not do this question justice, but I am encountering the following issue. My code is as follows:

```
void Model::processSession() {
    auto input_func = std::bind(&Ort::Session::GetInputNameAllocated, &(*session), _1, *allocator);
    auto output_func = std::bind(&Ort::Session::GetOutputNameAllocated, &(*session), _1, *allocator);
    input_names = getInputOrOutputNames(session->GetInputCount(), input_func); // This is a class variable
    std::string str(input_names[0]);
    std::cout << "Name 2: " << str << std::endl;
    output_names = getInputOrOutputNames(session->GetOutputCount(), output_func); // This is a class variable
}

template <typename Function>
std::vector<const char *> Model::getInputOrOutputNames(size_t size, Function name_allocator_func)
{
    std::vector<std::string> names_list;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        names_list.emplace_back(name_allocator_func(i).get());
    }

    std::vector<const char *> names_char(names_list.size(), nullptr);
    std::transform(std::begin(names_list), std::end(names_list), std::begin(names_char),
                   [&](const std::string &str)
                   { return str.c_str(); });
    std::string str(names_char[0]);
    std::cout << "Name 1: " << str << std::endl;
    return names_char;
}
```

When I call `processSession` on a `Model` object, I get the following output:

```
Name 1: input_values
Name 2: bA͌?
Name 1: logits
```

So it seems the problematic line is `input_names = getInputOrOutputNames(session->GetInputCount(), input_func);`. I'm not sure why querying `Name 2` returns random values as opposed to the expected output of `input_values`, when all I'm doing is just assigning the output to a class variable. Am I missing something simple here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::transform(std::begin(names_list), std::end(names_list), std::begin(names_char),
                   [&](const std::string &str)
                   { return str.c_str(); });
```

This lambda takes a reference to the `std::string` and stores a pointer to the underlying character stream. That means that pointer is only good as long as the source vector `names_list` is good. And `names_list` gets freed at the termination of `getInputOrOutputNames`, so as soon as that function is finished, so is your pointer. It's a *dangling pointer*, which means accessing it results in undefined behavior. Your program could print anything out, or do anything it pleased at this point.

The answer is to not let raw pointers float around in your code. You've got `std::string` values, so I'm not altogether clear why you go so far out of your way to specifically *get* a pointer to let it dangle. Stick with `std::string` and you'll find memory management much easier. It's still not automatic (C++ is a low-level language, after all), but it'll be much easier than trying to thread `char*` pointers through a bunch of lambdas.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't intend for it to be this way, but an input to an API requires a `std::vector<const char *>`, and for simplicity, I combined the logic to extract the `std::string` and the creation of the `std::vector<const char *>`